# Add new column with a specific row value in U-SQL

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have to extract records from a text file in U-SQL. The first row is different from other rows and it contains date. I have to skip the first row but I have to copy the date from first row and paste it into a new column for all rows. So this way in my final u-sql output query, the first column of every row will contain same data which was copied from the first line of the file. Please see the attached image file for more information.

[image]

Please suggest me the correct u-sql query to complete this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way. I used the SearchLog.tsv in the Samples to demonstrate this. At the top of the file, I added the row FROM `01JAN17 TO 31JAN17`.

```
//Skip the first row and read all the other rows
@searchlog = 
    EXTRACT UserId          int, 
            Start           DateTime, 
            Region          string, 
            Query           string, 
            Duration        int, 
            Urls            string, 
            ClickedUrls     string
    FROM @"/Samples/Data/SearchLogWithHeader.tsv"
    USING Extractors.Tsv(skipFirstNRows: 1);

//Extract all the text in the same file but don't parse out the individual columns
@searchlogAllText = 
    EXTRACT rowText string
    FROM @"/Samples/Data/SearchLogWithHeader.tsv"
    USING Extractors.Text(delimiter: '\n');

//Find a pattern that works for you and use the .NET expressions that match the string
@searchlogHeaderDate = 
    SELECT rowText.Split(' ')[1] AS FromDate FROM @searchlogAllText WHERE rowText.StartsWith("FROM");                                    

@output = SELECT * FROM @searchlogHeaderDate CROSS JOIN @searchlog;

OUTPUT @output 
    TO @"/Samples/Output/SearchLog_output.tsv"
    USING Outputters.Tsv();
```

Input:

```
FROM 01JAN17 TO 31JAN17
399266  2/15/2012 11:53:16 AM   en-us   how to make nachos  73  www.nachos.com;www.wikipedia.com    NULL
382045  2/15/2012 11:53:18 AM   en-gb   best ski resorts    614 skiresorts.com;ski-europe.com;www.travelersdigest.com/ski_resorts.htm   ski-europe.com;www.travelersdigest.com/ski_resorts.htm
382045  2/16/2012 11:53:20 AM   en-gb   broken leg  74  mayoclinic.com/health;webmd.com/a-to-z-guides;mybrokenleg.com;wikipedia.com/Bone_fracture   mayoclinic.com/health;webmd.com/a-to-z-guides;mybrokenleg.com;wikipedia.com/Bone_fracture
106479  2/16/2012 11:53:50 AM   en-ca   south park episodes 24  southparkstudios.com;wikipedia.org/wiki/Sout_Park;imdb.com/title/tt0121955;simon.com/mall   southparkstudios.com
906441  2/16/2012 11:54:01 AM   en-us   cosmos  1213    cosmos.com;wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmos:_A_Personal_Voyage;hulu.com/cosmos NULL
351530  2/16/2012 11:54:01 AM   en-fr   microsoft   241 microsoft.com;wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft;xbox.com NULL
640806  2/16/2012 11:54:02 AM   en-us   wireless headphones 502 www.amazon.com;reviews.cnet.com/wireless-headphones;store.apple.com www.amazon.com;store.apple.com
304305  2/16/2012 11:54:03 AM   en-us   dominos pizza   60  dominos.com;wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino's_Pizza;facebook.com/dominos  dominos.com
460748  2/16/2012 11:54:04 AM   en-us   yelp    1270    yelp.com;apple.com/us/app/yelp;wikipedia.org/wiki/Yelp,_Inc.;facebook.com/yelp  yelp.com
354841  2/16/2012 11:59:01 AM   en-us   how to run  610 running.about.com;ehow.com;go.com   running.about.com;ehow.com
354068  2/16/2012 12:00:33 PM   en-mx   what is sql 422 wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL;sqlcourse.com/intro.html;wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL    wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL
674364  2/16/2012 12:00:55 PM   en-us   mexican food redmond    283 eltoreador.com;yelp.com/c/redmond-wa/mexican;agaverest.com  NULL
347413  2/16/2012 12:11:55 PM   en-gr   microsoft   305 microsoft.com;wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft;xbox.com NULL
848434  2/16/2012 12:12:35 PM   en-ch   facebook    10  facebook.com;facebook.com/login;wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook facebook.com
604846  2/16/2012 12:13:55 PM   en-us   wikipedia   612 wikipedia.org;en.wikipedia.org;en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia  wikipedia.org
840614  2/16/2012 12:13:56 PM   en-us   xbox    1220    xbox.com;en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox;xbox.com/xbox360    xbox.com/xbox360
656666  2/16/2012 12:15:55 PM   en-us   hotmail 691 hotmail.com;login.live.com;msn.com;en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotmail    NULL
951513  2/16/2012 12:17:00 PM   en-us   pokemon 63  pokemon.com;pokemon.com/us;serebii.net  pokemon.com
350350  2/16/2012 12:18:17 PM   en-us   wolfram 30  wolframalpha.com;wolfram.com;mathworld.wolfram.com;en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Wolfram    NULL
641615  2/16/2012 12:19:55 PM   en-us   kahn    119 khanacademy.org;en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khan_(title);answers.com/topic/genghis-khan;en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khan_(name) khanacademy.org
321065  2/16/2012 12:20:03 PM   en-us   clothes 732 gap.com;overstock.com;forever21.com;footballfanatics.com/college_washington_state_cougars   footballfanatics.com/college_washington_state_cougars
651777  2/16/2012 12:20:33 PM   en-us   food recipes    183 allrecipes.com;foodnetwork.com;simplyrecipes.com    foodnetwork.com
666352  2/16/2012 12:21:03 PM   en-us   weight loss 630 en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight_loss;webmd.com/diet;exercise.about.com webmd.com/diet
```

Output:

```
"01JAN17"   399266  2012-02-15T11:53:16.0000000 "en-us" "how to make nachos"    73  "www.nachos.com;www.wikipedia.com"  "NULL"
"01JAN17"   382045  2012-02-15T11:53:18.0000000 "en-gb" "best ski resorts"  614 "skiresorts.com;ski-europe.com;www.travelersdigest.com/ski_resorts.htm" "ski-europe.com;www.travelersdigest.com/ski_resorts.htm"
"01JAN17"   382045  2012-02-16T11:53:20.0000000 "en-gb" "broken leg"    74  "mayoclinic.com/health;webmd.com/a-to-z-guides;mybrokenleg.com;wikipedia.com/Bone_fracture" "mayoclinic.com/health;webmd.com/a-to-z-guides;mybrokenleg.com;wikipedia.com/Bone_fracture"
"01JAN17"   106479  2012-02-16T11:53:50.0000000 "en-ca" "south park episodes"   24  "southparkstudios.com;wikipedia.org/wiki/Sout_Park;imdb.com/title/tt0121955;simon.com/mall" "southparkstudios.com"
"01JAN17"   906441  2012-02-16T11:54:01.0000000 "en-us" "cosmos"    1213    "cosmos.com;wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmos:_A_Personal_Voyage;hulu.com/cosmos"   "NULL"
"01JAN17"   351530  2012-02-16T11:54:01.0000000 "en-fr" "microsoft" 241 "microsoft.com;wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft;xbox.com"   "NULL"
"01JAN17"   640806  2012-02-16T11:54:02.0000000 "en-us" "wireless headphones"   502 "www.amazon.com;reviews.cnet.com/wireless-headphones;store.apple.com"   "www.amazon.com;store.apple.com"
"01JAN17"   304305  2012-02-16T11:54:03.0000000 "en-us" "dominos pizza" 60  "dominos.com;wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino's_Pizza;facebook.com/dominos"    "dominos.com"
"01JAN17"   460748  2012-02-16T11:54:04.0000000 "en-us" "yelp"  1270    "yelp.com;apple.com/us/app/yelp;wikipedia.org/wiki/Yelp,_Inc.;facebook.com/yelp"    "yelp.com"
"01JAN17"   354841  2012-02-16T11:59:01.0000000 "en-us" "how to run"    610 "running.about.com;ehow.com;go.com" "running.about.com;ehow.com"
"01JAN17"   354068  2012-02-16T12:00:33.0000000 "en-mx" "what is sql"   422 "wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL;sqlcourse.com/intro.html;wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL"  "wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL"
"01JAN17"   674364  2012-02-16T12:00:55.0000000 "en-us" "mexican food redmond"  283 "eltoreador.com;yelp.com/c/redmond-wa/mexican;agaverest.com"    "NULL"
"01JAN17"   347413  2012-02-16T12:11:55.0000000 "en-gr" "microsoft" 305 "microsoft.com;wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft;xbox.com"   "NULL"
"01JAN17"   848434  2012-02-16T12:12:35.0000000 "en-ch" "facebook"  10  "facebook.com;facebook.com/login;wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook"   "facebook.com"
"01JAN17"   604846  2012-02-16T12:13:55.0000000 "en-us" "wikipedia" 612 "wikipedia.org;en.wikipedia.org;en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia"    "wikipedia.org"
"01JAN17"   840614  2012-02-16T12:13:56.0000000 "en-us" "xbox"  1220    "xbox.com;en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox;xbox.com/xbox360"  "xbox.com/xbox360"
"01JAN17"   656666  2012-02-16T12:15:55.0000000 "en-us" "hotmail"   691 "hotmail.com;login.live.com;msn.com;en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotmail"  "NULL"
"01JAN17"   951513  2012-02-16T12:17:00.0000000 "en-us" "pokemon"   63  "pokemon.com;pokemon.com/us;serebii.net"    "pokemon.com"
"01JAN17"   350350  2012-02-16T12:18:17.0000000 "en-us" "wolfram"   30  "wolframalpha.com;wolfram.com;mathworld.wolfram.com;en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Wolfram"  "NULL"
"01JAN17"   641615  2012-02-16T12:19:55.0000000 "en-us" "kahn"  119 "khanacademy.org;en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khan_(title);answers.com/topic/genghis-khan;en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khan_(name)"   "khanacademy.org"
"01JAN17"   321065  2012-02-16T12:20:03.0000000 "en-us" "clothes"   732 "gap.com;overstock.com;forever21.com;footballfanatics.com/college_washington_state_cougars" "footballfanatics.com/college_washington_state_cougars"
"01JAN17"   651777  2012-02-16T12:20:33.0000000 "en-us" "food recipes"  183 "allrecipes.com;foodnetwork.com;simplyrecipes.com"  "foodnetwork.com"
"01JAN17"   666352  2012-02-16T12:21:03.0000000 "en-us" "weight loss"   630 "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight_loss;webmd.com/diet;exercise.about.com"   "webmd.com/diet"
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do something like this with normal U-SQL (ie not a custom UDO) and this [sample file](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9aa4750fe601a202effe54d63a367852):

```
USING rx = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex;

DECLARE @inputFilepath string = "input/input71.txt";
DECLARE @outputFilepath string = "output/output71.csv";


// Get the first line; use silent option to skip all other lines 
// ie which have more than one column
@file =
    EXTRACT headerLine string
    FROM @inputFilepath
    USING Extractors.Text(delimiter : '|', silent : true);


// Get the start date from the header
@header =
    SELECT
        headerLine,
        rx.Match(headerLine, @"FROM (?<startDate>\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\d{2}) TO (?<endDate>\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\d{2})").Groups["startDate"].ToString() AS startDate
    FROM @file
    WHERE headerLine.Contains("FROM");



// Get the rest of the lines; skip the header row explicity
// don't use 'silent' as it should not be required (as we're skipping header row)
@body =
    EXTRACT runDate string,
            col1 int,
            col2 int,
            col3 int
    FROM @inputFilepath
    USING Extractors.Text(delimiter : '|', skipFirstNRows : 1);


@result =
    SELECT h.startDate, p.*
    FROM @header AS h
         CROSS JOIN
             @body AS p;


// Export as csv
OUTPUT @result
TO @outputFilepath
USING Outputters.Csv(quoting:false);
```

My results:

[image: Results]

This was a simple example to demonstrate the power of U-SQL, pairing RegEx with set operations.  See if something similar will work for you.